# Contar distintos valores en distintas fechas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito ayuda con una consulta
Tengo la siguientes tablas: pedidos y tiempos

```
//pedidos
Id_Pedido   Id_Direccion    Id_Cliente  Id_Telefono fecha_creacion  Completo
1765        15780           15849       21909       2018-06-28      1
1778        15780           15857       21918       2018-06-28      1
1807        15780           15882       21943       2018-06-28      1
1819        15780           15891       21952       2018-06-28      1
1834        7945            7929        11490       2018-06-28      1

//tiempos
id_radios   id_pedido   id_operador id_ruta id_usuario  fecha       tiempo               tipo
3679        1834        103         22      54          2018-06-28  14:13:30.0911648    ASIGNA
3680        1778        153         6       54          2018-06-28  14:13:50.5571782    ENTREGA
3681        1807        100         4       54          2018-06-29  14:14:50.2997902    ENTREGA
3683        1765        62          28      54          2018-06-28  14:16:18.8867912    ENTREGA
3684        1819        182         32      65          2018-06-28  14:16:21.9147914    ASIGNA
3685        1819        182         32      65          2018-06-28  14:16:30.6167570    ENTREGA
```

Lo que necesito obtener es cuantos pedidos se entregaron en cada domicilio en distintas fechas, en este ejemplo el resultado deseado sería:

```
Id_Direccion pedidos fecha
15780        3       2018-06-28
15780        1       2018-06-29
7945         1       2018-06-28
```

¿Cómo sería el query para obtener este resultado?, he intentado algunas consultas con diferentes combinaciones de count() distinct() y group by pero no he tenido éxito aún.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que esto es lo que buscas

```
SELECT T.Id_Direccion, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT P.Id_Pedido) AS pedidos,
       T.fecha
       FROM pedidos P
       INNER JOIN tiempos T
           ON P.Id_Pedido    = T.id_pedido
       GROUP BY T.Id_Direccion,
                T.fecha
```

`join` entre las dos tablas y agrupamos por `Id_Direccion` y `fecha` lo que resta es contar los pedidos distintos en cada grupo, mediante `COUNT(DISTINCT P.Id_Pedido)`